# Use original linux user bashrc also as root user

Tags: linux, redhat, command-line-interface, root, bashrc

I extended the bashrc file of my linux user. This file contains extra aliases, functions, whatever is useful. It's synchronized with a playbook across our 100+ servers.

When i'm working on linux I often escale to the sudo user. this is frustrating bc when I escalate to this user I lose my bashrc settings.
Is there any way to keep these when I change to sudo.

Addendum:

1. Also we work with multiple linux users. With each there own bashrc.
2. I there is any way to source it. It needs to be done automatically. Or are there better alternatives?

OS: redhat

Comment: Just add the source command to the .bashrc of root?

Comment: *"I often escale to the sudo user"* - note that there is no such thing as a `THE sudo user` ; the `sudo`command allows to execute a command is any other user and the default user is root.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is one of the many reasons I have stopped customising my personal environments on any and all of the (customer) servers that I manage. When you become frustrated and crippled when they're not consistently available such customisations lose their benefits IMHO.

Two different approaches to combat that:

- combine all your teams shell profile customisations, aliases and functions and make them available to all users by publishing them in for example `/etc/profile.d/`

That has the benefit that you can create uniform work instructions and standardise approaches and avoids the situation where several versions of `your_useful_shell_function` exist in different peoples ~/.bashrc that don't get updated when you discover and fix a bug / edge case / incompatibility.

To continue relying on customisations from your personal environment consider to:

- Set up an appropriate alias/function in your personal profile and train yourself to use that instead of `sudo -i -u root`. That alias or function can then run `sudo -u root /bin/bash --rcfile ~ansible_usah/.bashrc` a and ensure that your personal bash RC file gets used instead of the default one for root. (or load a different personal bash rc-file that includes a subset/superset from the your customisations in your default ~/.bashrc)

Answer (score 0):

Does your .bashrc source another, system-wide, shared file?  Say `/etc/bash.bashrc`?
If so, consider putting your definitions *there* and *everybody* will get them.

If you only want a *smaller* number of users to have these settings, then create your own "shared" file and source that from the .bashrc of each user.